# I just deployed a sample sharepoint hosted app on a "Team Site". But it's UI is pretty messed up why does that happen so?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

I am working on sharepoint 2013 apps. And I want my app to be on a team site. So I deployed one sample test app on a team site. On a developer site it is working fine but on a team site it is not showing the page properly. What would be the reason?

Comment: Does your app use any custom styles? You can check browser dev tools and see what is causing the issue.

Comment: No its just the sample hello world app

Comment: It is hampering the sharepoint in-built UI, and I am not getting why it is happening..

Comment: My App is already getting deployed on the team site, does that require side loading, please somebody tell me I am stuck to the issue for a long time. It is showing me with the UI messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the master page.

Open the page in Google Chrome. 
Right click on any element and inspect in Browser Toolbar. 
See if you get a CSS File named oslo.css (while using oslo as master page)
or Correv.css (Seattle master page)

Delete all CSS.

Check if your UI is what you expect it to be. 
IF yes then the UI distortion is due to your style and default SharePoint styles.